# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' - PYTHON

Tags: python

Hola tengo un problema al quererme conectar a una base en postgres, estoy haciendo una aplicación web y quiero conectarla pero no puedo, el error es **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'**, entiendo que no está localizando el modulo pyscopsg2, pero si lo tengo instalado.

Importante señalar que esta aplicación **la tengo en un entorno virtual** y creo que va por ahí el tema, ya que en un proyecto no virtualizado, si tengo la conexión exitosa.

Esta aplicación la tengo cargada en Azure por que es un proyecto de prueba, pero no he logado conectarme a la base por este error.

Aquí se ve que no reconoce el modulo psycopg2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería muchísimo!

Comment: Tenes instalada varias versiones de Python en ese entorno???

Comment: Hola Dante, no, sólo tengo una 3.9.1, no he instalado otra  versión según yo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problemita se debe a que tienes el módulo instalado de manera global para instalarlo en el entorno virtual primero debes activar el entorno así:

```
myproject\Scripts\activate
```

Suponiendo que myproject es la raíz del directorio después introduce

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Debería poder instalar el módulo

Comment: Lo logre!! muchas gracias, lo pude instalar con pip3, te agradezco mucho y ya me quedó claro en donde debo de instalar cuando manejo entornos virtuales.

Comment: Me alegra mucho, sabes que la comunidad siempre está para ayudar!!!